# Position fixed sidebar with overflow scroll not scrolling to bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a fixed sidebar with dynamically loaded items onclick a `Load More` button.

I am attaching a class `fixed` to the parent sidebar div and `innerscroll` to the inner div to make it scrollable.

```
.fixed{position:fixed;top:0; bottom:0}
.innerscroll{overflow-y:scroll;height:100%}
```

Sidebar code

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sticky">
 <div class="cat-select"><select>
...
</select></div>
  <div class="item">
<section id="ajax-load-more">
... ajax content...
</section>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Can't figure out why after loading the next set of posts **I can't scroll to the end** such that the load-more button is visible.

Comment: I think the content on the right side is messing up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I got it. Just add two lines in your `.fixed` class:

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 45px; /* added */
   min-height: 0 !important; /* added */
}
```

And this will work exactly as you expected. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Debajyoti Das for the bounty. :P

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because you have the inner-scroll div set to height:100%.  I changed it to height: 90% - the button is now visible, and your content is still scrollable.  I don't know why setting it to height 100% would knock out your button, though.

Comment: It's causing an issue because `.cat-select` has a height of 22px. Setting `height: 100%` sets `.innerscroll` to the height of the parent, no matter what other children are in the parent div. So if the parent is 500px, `.innerscroll` will also be 500px, just bumped down by 22px. Bumping it down causes this 22px to be hidden at the bottom of the div. You could also use `height: calc(100% - 22px)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust a few things to get it to work.

First thing is your div sidebar to the class stick

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sticky fixed">
```

Once you've done that then simply modify the CSS for #sidebar line 22 style.css your saying 1000px but really

```
#sidebar {
min-height: 50%;
max-height: 95%;
}
```

This makes it work on my side. Also I might be wrong and you might not need to do the DIV so try the CSS first then try the DIV and the CSS if just the CSS doesn't fix it.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

### CSS is ( over ) compensating for your ( hidden ) 45px tall header bar!

All you need to do is bravely & mysteriously use `bottom: 45px` and **not** `bottom: 0px` in your CSS:

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 45px;
}
```

I have your demo interface working perfectly if I open my Element Inspector and change only the above.

Using percentage based heights is not an exact fix for you ( or anyone ). There will be gaps that way.

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking the `min-height: 1000px` off `#sidebar`. Then choose your poison below for `.innerscroll`.

It's hiding the button at the bottom because `.cat-select` has a height of 22px. Setting `height: 100%` sets `.innerscroll` to the height of the parent, no matter what other children are in the parent div. So if the parent is 500px, `.innerscroll` will also be 500px, just bumped down by 22px. Bumping it down causes this 22px to be hidden at the bottom of the div. You can see this by setting `position: absolute; top: 0` on `.innerscroll`.

Three options (number three being my personal choice): **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LdhB9/1/)**

1. You can use `height: calc(100% - 22px)` if calc works for your implementation (caniuse.com).
2. Or you can shrink `.innerscroll` as has been specified in other answers (`height: 98%` or whatever works for your case).
3. Or you can set `position: absolute; top: 0;` to `.innerscroll`, then set `margin-top: 22px` on  `.listing`. This will set the scrolling div with overflow-y to match top and bottom of the parent, and cause the 22px push down inside that div.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... Helped me a lot to understand whats going on.